# How to add a drop-down menu to a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, paintcomponent

So, I have a main method that contains something like this:

```
public class ArcDrawer {
    public static void main ( String [ ] args ){
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Arc");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        points p = new points();
        f.add(p);
        f.setSize(850, 850);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Then, the class `points` contains a `paintComponent` method. This method takes a variable, `complexity`, and draws a circle based on the number. What I would like to do is add a drop-down menu and confirm button to my `JFrame` that can change this complexity variable and then draw the circle. Any suggestions? I have no idea how I would pass a variable to the `paintComponent` method.

Comment: You should look into adding a `JComboPane` into your GUI.

Comment: @Tdorno JComboBox? I'm looking at the java documentation and don't see JComboPane..

Answer (score 1):

> I have no idea how I would pass a variable to the paintComponent method..

You don't. You set a property of the Points class. Then the paintComponent() method can reference the property during painting.

For example the Points class should have methods like `setComplexity(...)` and `getComplexity()`.

Also, follow Java naming conventions. Class names should start with an upper case character. "points" should be "Points".  Any textbook or turorial you read will follow this convention so don't make up your own conventions.

Comment: I know that now. I wrote this at the beginning of the semester before we went over naming conventions, haha.

So, inside of the Points class, I could have a constructor like so:
     int complexity;
 
 public Points(int c){
  complexity = c;
 }

and then back in my main, I could then take the info from the dropdown and instantiate the class using
    Points p = new Points(whateverinthere);